# Issue a unit test on a Gulp file using Karma & Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner, browserify

I wrote a unit test for a Gulp file. The test runs through karma using Jasmine Framework (safari/chrome). 
Knowing that Karma runs the test file, specified in the json config file, in the browser, it should have a way to run Node's modules in the browser.
After researching, I found that by using Browserify I'll be able to require modules in the browser.

When I write this command

> browserify ./Test/GulpTest.js -o ./Test/TEST.js -d

The new TEST.js seems to be big

and I run the following command to start the test on the new TEST.js

> karma start karma.conf.js

I get this error:

> gulp input stream
>       ✗ should compile from ts to js    TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined
>         at Object. (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:75226:20)
>         at Object.252._process (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:75284:4)
>         at s (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:1:254)
>         at /Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:1:305
>         at Object.31../lib/PluginError (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:3530:9)
>         at Object.239../lib/PluginError (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:75113:21)
>         at s (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:1:254)
>         at /Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:1:305
>         at Object.229.deprecated (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:74824:13)
>         at s (/Users/Snap/Desktop/Demo App/Test/TEST.js:1:254)
>
> Chrome 44.0.2403 (Mac OS X 10.10.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR
>   (0.037 secs / 0.03 secs)

```
    it("should compile from ts to js", function () {
            var gulp = require("gulp");
            var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
            var lazy = require("gulp-load-plugins");
            var fs = require('graceful-fs');
            var should = require('should');
            var join = require('path').join;


            /*
            * * * Compile Typescript to JavaScript 
            */
            gulp.task("ts-compiler", function () {
                return gulp.src("./Test/lib/file.ts")
                           .pipe(lazy.typescript({
                                // Generates corresponding .map file. 
                                sourceMap : false,

                                // Generates corresponding .d.ts file. 
                                declaration : true,

                                // Do not emit comments to output. 
                                removeComments : false,

                                // Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. 
                                noImplicitAny : false,

                                // Skip resolution and preprocessing. 
                                noResolve : false,

                                // Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'   
                                module : "amd",

                                // Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5' 
                                target : "ES5"
                            }))
                            .pipe(gulp.dest("./Test/lib/dest"));
            });

            gulp.start("ts-compiler", function () {
                console.log("compiling...");
                should.exist("./Test/lib/dest/file.js");
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Gulp inside karma and jasmine—you're running it as if it is a front-end library, and it is not.

You need to use a back-end testing library. You can still use jasmine, you just have to use it through nodejs, which is how gulp runs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine

You might be interested to see how I wrote unit tests for my gulp tasks where I work: https://github.com/Lostmyname/lmn-gulp-tasks/tree/master/test